# js/module how to write async io in global/module scope?

Tags: javascript, optimization, webpack, es6-modules

In `javascript/es6` module programming for `browser` env(with `webpack`), I want to optimize my process of resources loading

say, in a module, we export a `class`

```js
// in a js module
export default class MyClass {
    constructor(){
        new Promise(resolve => {
            // this async IO always return unchanged remote resources
            new AsyncIOLoader.load(remoteResources, resolve)
        }).then(rawData =>
                // a slow non-IO computation is needed 
                this.data = SlowTransform(rawData) 
        )

    }
    show() {
        return this.data
    }
}
```

if client code intends to use `for` loop to create many instances of my class.
that `SlowTranform` would be repeated many times, with **SAME** input and output.

And now I want to optimize it by lifting it into module scope(global scope).

for normal variable(that doesn't need async IO), it's easy:

```js
// in a js module

//SlowTransform is still slow, but we only execute it once
const data = SlowTransform(rawData)

export default class MyClass {
    constructor(){
        this.data = data
    }
    show() {
        return this.data
    }
}
```

But How do we achieve this in facing of `rawData` that should be retrieved by **Async IO** ?

I think a normal `Promise/then` in module scope would not guarantee the availability of `data` when client calls `new MyClass()`

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43431550/async-await-class-constructor/43433773#43433773

Comment: Both your concepts here are deeply flawed.  You can't do either one of these this way.  As this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you show us your attempted solution and don't show us the overall calling code and what problem you're really trying to solve with this code, we can't really know what more proper and correct design to suggest.

Comment: You pretty much never want to put asynchronous operations in a constructor for a whole variety of reasons.  For a discussion of this part of the problem, see [Asynchronous operations in constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49905178/asynchronous-operations-in-constructor/49906064#49906064).

Comment: If lifting the asynchronous operation out of the constructor and doing it before, then just create all your objects in the completion callback from your asynchronous operation.  Asynchronous is non-blocking so there's never going to be a solution that doesn't involve a callback, a promise by itself with `.then()` or a promise with `async/await`.