# How to execute asynchronous functions in the constructor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript

I am trying to implement the Customer object in NodeJs and that the instance is able to collect its data.

```js
class CustomerModel extends Model {
  public customer

  constructor(email:string) {
    super();
    this.collection = 'customer';
    this.customer = await CustomerLayer.getCustomerByEmail(email);
  }
}
```

But I can't have an asynchronous constructor. I have seen that in Javascript you can do the following:

```js
const sleep = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
    class Example {
      constructor () {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
          try {
            await sleep(1000);
            this.value = 23;
          } catch (ex) {
            return reject(ex);
          }
          resolve(this);
        });
      }
    }

    (async () => {
      // It works as expected, as long as you use the await keyword.
      const example = await new Example();

      console.log(example instanceof Example);
      console.log(example.value);
    })();
```

But I think it is not correct to return the data from the constructor.
Is there any correct way to call asynchronous methods from the constructor?

Comment: I think this is a mistake about async/await...

Comment: In this situation, I usually declare an `init` method which I have to call manually after creating the instance. I find it much cleaner, and a constructor method is supposed to return an instance, not a promise

Comment: something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43431550/async-await-class-constructor/43433773#answer-50885340

Comment: [You don't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24398699/1048572).

Comment: Multiple options for [Asynchronous operations in a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49905178/asynchronous-operations-in-constructor/49906064#49906064).

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't do it in constructor. Probably `init` method fits this use case better.

```
class CustomerModel extends Model {
  public customer

  constructor(email:string) {
    super();
    this.collection = 'customer';
  }
  async init() {
   this.customer = await CustomerLayer.getCustomerByEmail(email);
  }
}
```

```
const myClass = new CustomerModel();
await myClass.init();
```

You could also consider creating a static method to return the instance which internally create object and init.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. You have a few options here:

- You can explicitly return a Promise from the constructor (construct it via `new Promise`). This is what you're doing in your second code. `await` can always be substituted with the Promise constructor and `.then`. But, it's *pretty weird*, since one would always expect the result of `new Example()` to then be an `instanceof Example` - one *wouldn't* expect `new Example()` to result in a Promise. This is what your first code would look like using this method:

```
class CustomerModel extends Model {
  public customer

  constructor(email:string) {
    super();
    this.collection = 'customer';
    return CustomerLayer.getCustomerByEmail(email)
      .then((customerByEmailResolveValue) => {
        this.customerByEmailResolveValue = customerByEmailResolveValue;
        return this;
      });
  }
}
const customerProm = new CustomerModel('foo');
customerProm.then((actualCustomerInstance) => {
  // use actualCustomerInstance
});
```

- In the constructor, assign the Promise to a property of the instance. Then, when you need to consume that value, call `.then` on the property:

```
class CustomerModel extends Model {
  public customer
  constructor(email:string) {
    super();
    this.collection = 'customer';
    this.customerProm = CustomerLayer.getCustomerByEmail(email);
  }
}
const customer = new CustomerModel('foo');
customer.customerProm.then((result) => {
  // use result;
});
```

- You can also retrieve the value *before* creating the instance, then pass it in:

```
class CustomerModel extends Model {
  public customer
  constructor(email:string, customerByEmailResolveValue) {
    super();
    this.collection = 'customer';
    this.customer = customerByEmailResolveValue;
  }
}
CustomerLayer.getCustomerByEmail(email)
  .then((customerByEmailResolveValue) => {
    const customer = new CustomerModel('foo', customerByEmailResolveValue);
  });
```