# How to make object constructor wait for promise to settle before returning?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

I'm making an "Image" constructor function. It saves metadata from arguments, and fetches the image (based on metadata).

```
function Image(filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
    fetch(`https://example.com/${this.filename}`)
        .then( response => response.blob())
        .then( blob => {
            this.objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            this.timestamp = Date.now();
        })
}
```

However, when ran with `new Image('image.jpg')`, it returns an object with only **filename** property, and **objectURL** with **timestamp** are appended later.
What I want is constructor function to wait for **objectURL** and **timestamp** before returning an object.

Thanks in advance!

Additionally, you can see [demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5S1O.png) of running it in console, where *title* and *number* are arguments, *filename* is computed from them and used in real link, and *dataURL*, *timestamp*, *pinned* properties are set inside *then()*.

Comment: You can't make Javascript "wait" in that way.  I would suggest the options here: [Asynchronous operations in constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49905178/asynchronous-operations-in-constructor/49906064#49906064).

Answer (score 1):

A nice pattern is the builder, likely referenced in one of the links above, although I did not see an example using functional instantiation. Define a static method directly on the class to act as a factory in building instances that require async operations.

```
function Image({ filename, ...rest }) {
  this.filename = filename;
  this.dataUrl = rest.dataUrl;
  this.timestamp = rest.timestamp;
}

Image.build = async function(filename) {
    const fetchedData = await asyncFetchAndBlobHandling(filename);
    return new Image({ filename, ...fetchedData })
}

const imgInstance = await Image.build(photo.jpg);
```