# Typescript/javascript method being invoked before constructor

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql

So I have an issue where Im creating a postgres class. However when connecting to my DB I noticed that a function is being invoked before the constructor. Here is my code

```
import { Client } from 'pg';
import { Config } from './config/postgres'

class PostgresHandler {
    client: Client;
    status: boolean | undefined = false;
    constructor(){
        this.client = new Client(Config)
        this.client.connect(err => {
            if (err) {
              console.error('connection error', err.stack)
              this.status = false
            } else {
              console.log('connected')
              this.status = true
            }
          })
    }


    retreiveImageData() {
        console.log(this.status)
    }
}

export {PostgresHandler}
```

Invoking this class

```
 var psql = new PostgresHandler_1.PostgresHandler();
 psql.retreiveImageData()
```

Output:

```
false
connected
```

How can I get my constructor to run first before any other method in the class?
I'm trying to make a connection to postgres and set the connection status to true.

Comment: Please see [How do I return the response from an aynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/438992), which this duplicates. In other words, obviously the constructor must run first--but you're calling an async method in the constructor, which returns at an arbitrary time in the future.

Comment: First, as others have explained, you need to understand how non-blocking, asynchronous operations work and what that means for your coding.  Then, you can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49905178/asynchronous-operations-in-constructor/49906064#49906064) about using asynchronous operations in a constructor which have another set of issues because the constructor HAS to return the new object so it can't easily return a promise to let the caller know when the asycnhronous operation is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are performing an asynchronous operation in your class constructor. `this.client.connect` takes a function as an argument in order to let you know when it's done.

So your synchronous code executes in this order:

1. Class constructor runs
2. `this.client.connect` is called, and is passed a function to run when it (eventually) connects.
3. The constructor finishes executing.
4. `psql.retreiveImageData()` is executed
5. Some unknown time later, the callback passed to `connect` is executed.

Normally, you would wrap this in a promise and await it before doing anything that required a connection to be established. But this is a bit more tricky because a class constructor cannot be `async`.

A good solution would be to break up connecting with creating the class. This gives you a bit more control.

And it's exactly what the `pg` library does:

```
this.client = new Client(Config)
this.client.connect(err => { //...
```

Note how creating the instance, and connecting are two steps.

You need to do the same thing:

```
class PostgresHandler {
    client: Client;
    status: boolean | undefined = false;
    constructor(){
        this.client = new Client(Config)
    }

    async connect() {
      try {
        await this.client.connect()
        console.log('connected')
        this.status = true
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('connection error', err.stack)
        this.status = false
      }
    }

    retreiveImageData() {
        console.log(this.status)
    }
}
```

And now you can `await` the connection of your custom class with:

```
async function someAsyncFunction() {
  var psql = new PostgresHandler();
  await psql.connect()
  psql.retreiveImageData() // Should log true once the connection is established.
}
someAsyncFunction()
```

Or:

```
var psql = new PostgresHandler();
psql.connect().then(() => {
  psql.retreiveImageData() // Should log true once the connection is established.
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=31&ssc=4&pln=28&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYQDbAKYDt4F84BmUEIcA5GAOZkDcAUHQCYYDGqAhlBnCxFgM7xkfAsEoAuOOywBPOAHp5cMFxjZGcGAAtg-OLqlwAbu3QbeWUZQZt2-PQAUIgyl34AJaY1QYoiOnCBPOjYMJJomDj0QXCC7DAArvySAEYQED7ScAA+cAlYzKJYGBoAvISm-BjRQRaCUAksMNAAFACUCAExQdq6AHRskfDlxQDuKCE4LcKWYm1dgbgMMXYyWCw8fMVN7f7dmlBynfuB7KPswPC9-AOTMANbrDDtC911GRh9qBCULWQW2zUjDI8xOmh0NziiT05RgDQwr0WPHiLC0cBavigbT2J3ePj6mNa-0eTWAfDghKgZAANBSoFA+nEWABrUEna6MmDxJJwcoESoI-ZLGJLV6qLjAIwYACSIHYlAwABF4uxdsdcXx+B8vj8WhyoUk2Ys6KKTH4wPwAI6oXlwMZwJwuNyeAo+KDtegW60PLCA9p9bTYFq7UoAPhxXtQfXFGElMrlCuVXN2ijgAGUtBAEqgNN9KAcEtw+CxuIHNr6nmSsPo9Bg4il0PwtCU+ibsQxU9AGKt1oR8qTyVqQBgAIL8NYsABi-ZgVbVXTNyitNpGGHGjpgrjrLu8vg9XTOF3gkZ9frZJ5jcdl8qVKpTSgzWZzcDzBaL61LzfLgKrNYp9cbZtGFbJYh1Hcd1mndZZz4dogA)

Comment: Very clean and concise answer! This is correct and was able to acheive what I was aiming for. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help! Don’t forget to click the check mark to select this as the correct answer if it’s the one that help you most.

Answer (score 0):

`this.client.connect` is starting an asynchronous task, which runs in the background. Your other code keeps running while this call is being processed. Therefore, while the connection is being established `this.status` will be false.

Solution:
Wait for the callback to be called before calling `retrieveImageData`.